# Control + Alt + a Function in Remote Desktop on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, apple-remote-desktop

I'm on a Mac and I'm using Remote Desktop to connect to my Windows machine. There's a shortcut needed in one particular program that is Alt+Control+F11. How do I go about doing that?

F11 seems to require fn+the low volume key. And then from there I'm not entirely sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have never used Remote Desktop, but you can configure OS X to use the function keys as standard function keys: System Preferences>Keyboard>"Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys".

Comment: I'll try that and report back.